# How to retrieve header of a failed ajax request

Tags: jquery

I am using following ajax code for retrieving the size of a remote file:

```
request = $.ajax({
 type: "HEAD",
 url: vurl,
 success: function () {
  var vsize = request.getResponseHeader("Content-Length");
  alert("Size is " + vsize);
  }         
});
```

But due to some problem it's failing each time. But when I inspected it through firebug, I got the following response header:

```
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Alternate-Protocol  80:quic
Cache-Control   private, max-age=23114
Content-Length  655680
Content-Type    video/3gpp
Date    Mon, 03 Feb 2014 21:35:10 GMT
Expires Mon, 03 Feb 2014 21:35:10 GMT
Last-Modified   Tue, 13 Mar 2012 13:30:30 GMT
Server  gvs 1.0
x-content-type-options  nosniff
```

we can clearly see that header contains the size of the file which is the purpose of the code. Please anybody suggest me how to retrieve it. Any small help will be appreciated.

Comment: Well obviously your `success` handler isn't going to run unless the call actually succeeds, so try adding an `error` handler. Of course, it might be better to figure out why it doesn't work...

Comment: I already tried that :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a PHP proxy: http://benalman.com/projects/php-simple-proxy/

**Why use Simple PHP Proxy?**

- Requested URLs can be white-listed and validated against a regex.
- Optionally forward client cookies / SID to the remote server.
- Optionally forward configurable User Agent to the remote server.
- Requests can use either GET or POST request methods.
- Remote data can be delivered as-is with all remote headers intact (disabled by
  default to limit XSS vulnerabilites).
- Remote data can be wrapped in a JSON/P structure that includes status codes and remote headers (JSONP
  disabled by default to limit abuse).
- If using JSON/P and remote data
  is valid JSON, it will be merged into the resulting data object.

Answer (score 0):

Some server disallow access to HEAD, try to work arround using the complete callback:

```
complete: function (xhr)
{
    var fileSize = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Length');

    console.log(fileSize);
}
```

Comment: console response is null :(

Comment: could you provide the file url?

Comment: http://r16---sn-cvh7zn7k.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ms=au&ratebypass=yes&id=f9976767cb796368&sparams=id,ip,ipbits,itag,ratebypass,source,upn,expire&mt=1391465723&sver=3&expire=1391490324&source=youtube&upn=8uiVyZBBGIE&fexp=934701,916602,930102,916626,936110,941504,936910,936913&ipbits=0&key=yt5&ip=59.89.129.158&itag=43&mv=m&signature=8E7A9FF3468041895AB681888CEF363886B2E2E6.4ECB5A3914D13EC93E490B0BF1F8DF59F36976C9

Comment: That URL does not send any CORS headers, so how do you even expect an AJAX call for that to work without failing because of the same origin policy?

Comment: Response header have content length. That's why I thought it will work. Is it possible?